# Error when trying to open "Trash" through Nautilus. Any alternatives?

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash

Pretty simple error. When I try to open "Trash" through Nautilus, I get a dialog box displaying the following:

'Sorry, could not display all the contents of “trash:///”: Operation not supported'

I need a file (several thousand, actually) that I accidentally deleted this morning.

Google has very little to say on this particular error. Most of the forum posts I've found are 5+ years old, or have gone unresolved. So I'm pretty hopeless. Are there any alternatives to using the Trash utility to restore files?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The trash directory is located at  /home/username/.local/share/Trash .

Underneath that directory, "files" should contain any files you have deleted.

You can try opening nautilus, going to your home directory, and pressing Ctrl + H (The key combination for showing hidden files) and browsing to that path, or you can do it from a terminal.

Take your choice.

I hope that helps.

EDIT1:

You can install trash-cli using "sudo apt-get install trash-cli" for a command line interface to manage your trash. It has a command restore-trash which should do what you are wanting.

EDIT2: Have you tried running "gksudo nautilus", and then going to trash via places, or pressing Ctrl + L and typing trash:/// ?

EDIT3:
I have modified the python script that comes with trash-cli for the restore-trash utility to enable multiple restores. (Sorry didn't have enough time to do it from user input, but it will restore the first 10001 items in your trash) Open /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trashcli/trash.py in a text editor and navigate down to def run(self):
replace everything from (and including) that line down to def for_all_trashed_file_in_dir(self, action, dir): with the following:

```
def run(self):

    trashed_files = []
    self.for_all_trashed_file_in_dir(trashed_files.append, self.curdir())

    if not trashed_files:
        self.report_no_files_found()
    else :
        for i, trashedfile in enumerate(trashed_files):
            self.println("%4d %s %s" % (i, trashedfile.deletion_date, trashedfile.path))
    index=range(10000)
for item in index:
    trashed_files[item].restore()
```

The next time you run restore-trash it will restore the first 10001 items in your trash.

Let me know if you have any problems, and I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you saying that I have to manually restore the file structure of over 9000 files? EDIT: To be more clear, when I deleted the files and folders, every folder was extracted from its parent folder and placed in ~/.local/share/Trash. In short, the folder hierarchy is totally screwed up. I do not think a simple mv will solve this issue, if that is what you're implying the solution is.

Comment: Response to your edit: Tried it. Ironically, the trash-cli tool (restore-trash, in particular) is itself a piece of trash. Try it out and see what I mean. It only lets you restore a single file at a time... WHY?? EDIT: trash-restore => restore-trash

Comment: 'gksudo nautilus' gave me the same error. I tried doing Ctrl + L and typing trash:///, which gave me a dialog box saying "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again. Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file ~/trash:: No such file or directory" So I thought, "OK, just move your ~/.local/share/Trash to ~/trash", which I did. Then doing a Ctrl + L and typing trash:/// just gave me the same dialog box. (I did make sure to change it to lower "t".) EDIT: specifics

Comment: I got rid of the link to .py script and just posted the changed code.